# session_start() followed by header() causing error

Tags: php

I have the following code in a PHP file called via Ajax (note - the code is a stripepd down version of the actual code, but still produces an error:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $response = array(
        'status'=>'abc',
        'a'=>'abc',
        'b'=>'abc',
        'c'=>'abc'
    );

    header('X-JSON: '.json_encode($response));
    exit;
```

?>

There are absolutely no spaces or anything before the opening

Yet when I call the script I get:

> '[11-Aug-2009 14:56:13] PHP Notice:  A
>   session had already been started -
>   ignoring session_start() in
>   \test\action.php on line 2
>
> [11-Aug-2009 14:56:13] PHP Warning: 
>   Cannot modify header information -
>   headers already sent by (output
>   started at \test\action.php:2) in
>   \test\action.php on line 10'

Line 2 is the session_start() command and line 10 is the header() command.

So PHP is telling me that it has ignored the session_start, and then immediately telling me that actually that line produced output....whats going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, believe it or not, the criminal output is......

```
'[11-Aug-2009 14:56:13] PHP Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in \test\action.php on line 2
```

Either suppress error messages (bad idea in development) Or find where you started the session (which is really how you need to solve this)

Comment: Gah - yes, you're right. FWIW I work on two different PHP projects, one of which has auto-started sessions, and this one which doesnt. I hadnt changed my PHP.ini, so the rogue error was being output. The problem was compounded by it being an ajax request, so the error wasnt as obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to this [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122395/php-session-and-path-setting/1122646).

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's this annoying little bugger called BOM (Byte Order Mark) creeping in your file. It's possible if you've encoded that file as utf-8, and you can catch it with firebug for example.

Answer (score -1):

Use ob_start();